# Facebook connect -

Tags: facebook

I  want to use face book connect on my website. And i cant find proper Documentation on face book to use it. Can you help me out with it ?

Answer (score 3):

Start here

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Answer (score 0):

[This website](http://codethatworkedforme.blogspot.com/2011/08/facebook-connect.html) gives you a start up for facebookconnect.